# file:///store/home/user/myfile.txt doesn't work on bold 9900

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I'm building an app for BB and I made a class to store some logs in a file on the phone. This is my code:

```
public class Logger {
    public static void trace(String line) {
        FileConnection fc = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        if (ApplicationConstant.DEBUG_ENABLED) {
            try {
                fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///store/home/user/HabbleLog.txt");
                if (!fc.exists()) fc.create();  // create the file if it doesn't exist
                outStream = fc.openOutputStream(fc.fileSize());
                outStream.write((line + "\n").getBytes());
                System.out.println(line);
            } catch (Exception ioe) {
                System.out.println(ioe.toString());
            } finally {
                try {
                    outStream.close();
                    fc.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.toString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works well on a Bold 9700 but when I run the app on a Bold 9900 I get a NullPointer Exception on the line

```
    fc = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///store/home/user/HabbleLog.txt");
```

Someone knows why? Is there a fs difference that I have to consider?
Thanks.

Comment: Just for experimental purposes, try path `file:///Store/home/user/HabbleLog.txt`

Comment: @RafaelOsipov On the bold 9700 now I get an uncaughtException and on the 9900 I have an UnsupportedoperationException

Comment: Seems it is a bug in a RIM OS implementation. Ask your question here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/bd-p/java_dev It is official BlackBerry Developers forum.